# Migrate SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, database

Actually I want to migrate a large dataset to another database which already has some data. Data Schema is same in Both DB. Scenario is that my client has application that already running in production and he had given me some new requirements to implement that. after implementation he want to test new requirements on temporary production server for acceptant testing on 2 Locations. So that I have attached existing database to new production server. Now I want to write a DB script that migrate data of location between before and after acceptance testing. My problem is that Ticket ID of my table has identity and running application on both data servers will insert same TicketIDs.  Now when I migrate the data, there is a conflict of Primary Key. My schema of parent table is as follow.

```
TicketID, Identity(1,1) int
LocationID int
Problem varchar(500)
IssueDate DateTime
```

Another issue is that Ticket ID is print on Customer Receipt and client don't want to change Ticket No.

Please suggest me solutions of this problem.

One Solution is that to add a column OldTicketID but for that I need to change my application code and I don't want to change that there are many child table of that.

Comment: You don't even say what your DBMS is. I've assumed Microsoft SQL Server (for the `Identity` bit). You can correct it yourself if it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the identity column to only generate odd numbers on the old dataset (identity(1,2)) and only even numbers on the new dataset (identity(seed,2)).

Seed should be set to the highest ticketid that's currently in the production system, so there wouldn't be any conflicts with the ids.